# Measure Water-Use Efficiency without using carbon isotope fractionation?

Tags: plant-physiology

I read "Measurements of delta (C-13) in C3 species may usefully contribute to the selection for transpiration efficiency." I think the device to measure carbon isotope fractionation is very expensive. Are there some easier ways to measure the water-use efficiency of plants, please? Thank you.